# What microphone (sound sensor) that can work with Arduino to detect gunshot?

Tags: microcontroller, microphone, sound

I am working on a project to detect a very loud sound/Pop(like gunshot).I am using a microcontroller like Arduino. Currently I am using this simple  [sound sensor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B073S39CG4). But the issue is, it is very sensitive, I connected it with 3.3V and the highest it gets is around 560's from analog read, whether it is a simple clap or loud bang, it maxes-out at 568. I have tried to adjust the potentialmeter but no difference.

Can this sensor measure gunshot intensity? If not what sensor can I use?

Comment: You havn't given sufficient information. How close to the gun are you?

Comment: Why are you using a 3.3v supply?  An LM358 supplied by only 3.3v isn't going to be able to access more than part of the range of a 5v ADC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon visiting the manufacturer website and looking at the schematic they provide, the most likely cause of the problem you are having is that the pre-amp that follows the mic capsule has too much gain.[Microphone Sound Detector](https://robotdyn.com/pub/media/0G-00004696==Sens-SoundDetect/DOCS/Schematic==0G-00004696==Sens-SoundDetect.pdf)

For a first attempt, simply remove R4.  This changes the pre-amp to have unity gain.  If the output signal is now too low, choose a suitable value for R4 that gives you the gain that you need.

It's hard to give you more concrete information because the manufacturer does not provide component values on the schematic.  But this should get you started.

One of the other answers suggested monitoring the output signal with an oscilloscope.  This is great advice and you should do that if at all possible.

Comment: Thanks Dwayne. Do I really need an oscilloscope if I can read the analog output signal through serial port which is what I have been doing ?

Answer (score 1):

If your sensor is too sensitive then you could do well to find ways to muffle the sound that the sensor receives. This could be anything from putting cloth, felt or even paper over the sensor. It could even go so far as to place the sensor with insulation around it and allow some sound to enter the sensor through the insulation.

Comment: The described problem is one of improper circuit design, not sensor overload.

Answer (score 1):

Piezo disks are a usable, insensitive, microphone for gunshot, depending on distance

A gunshot definitely can slap the electret microphones diaphragm into the stops if close. You need to look at the microphone output with an oscilloscope to see if the mcirophone is saturating, or the amplifier following it.

Comment: The distance can be couple of meters away to 20 meters.Sorry i didnt get you here .......You need to look at the microphone output with an oscilloscope to see if the mcirophone is saturating, or the amplifier following it.

Comment: the microphone capsule has an output pin. You need to look at that signal while you yell/clap/hit hammers etc, to see what the max level is. Then see if your gunshot is significantly less than that, which it must be to make a linear measurement.

Comment: Thanks Henry.But When I clap or make a very loud sound like gunshot, the max level is the same for both.I was expecting the gunshot to be higher.

Answer (score 0):

The product description says that the potentiometer adjusts the threshold for the *digital* output of the microphone, not the *analog* output. You need to measure the voltage of the digital output of the microphone to determine whether the sound level is past the threshold set by the potentiometer or not.

Answer (score 0):

## Simple answer:

Put tape over mic and seal tight until you can peak detect a linear range over 40dB or 1 to 100%.

———

This is a physics issue with sound isolation from ambient and general handling and not about detection.  You could use a ceramic cap and amplifier to detect a gunshot with a suitable substrate but again the background low frequency noise must be isolated.

Acoustic measurement devices are usually high quality wideband cardiod moving coil microphones not cheap electrets.  But with skill, one could calibrate cheap mics with suitable peak and hold detection and very low gain. Your PCB is clipping it.  But like any measurement device , directional control gain and and acoustic measurement of "Loudness" according to Fletcher Munson curves are very dynamic so there is poor correlation with distance with loudness. Also reflections from structures nearby can amplify the sound levels.
)

[image]